Holomorphic surjective map
Let $\Omega_1=\lbrace{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| < 1\rbrace} $and $\Omega_2= \mathbb{C}$. Which of the following statements are true?

There exists a holomorphic surjective map $f:\Omega_1\to\Omega_2$.

2 There exists a holomorphic surjective map $f:\Omega_2\to\Omega_1$.

There exists a holomorphic injective map $f:\Omega_1\to\Omega_2$.
There exists a holomorphic injective map $f:\Omega_2\to\Omega_1$.

Option 2 and 4 are not true by Liouvlle’s theorem.
For option 3, $f(z) = z$, true But I don’t have any clue whether option 1 is true or not. I tried to disprove this by using theorems, but I failed.
I also didn’t get any examples of such a holomorphic surjective map.Anyone, please help with this. Also,  please check my answer for the other three options.

Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4033266/surjective-holomorphic-map-from-a-domain-to-mathbbc

This is also quite interesting but I don't see how it exactly helps.

Just note that $(z-1)^2$ is a surjective map from the closed plane $\Re z\ge1$ to the plane and then use your favorite Riemann map to send the unit disc to $\Re z>0$; the composition is surjective by construction

Thanks, you are right. I was about to finish my answer

@HyperbolicPDEfriend thanks for link post it’s makes me clear.

I constructed this surjective holomorphic map $f(z)=\frac{-4z}{1+z^2}$

Thanks for your explanation @Conrad

Now I get it: This is a condensed version of this. Choose an analytic bijection $f:\Omega_1 \rightarrow \lbrace z \in \mathbb{C}: \mathrm{Im}(z)> -1\rbrace$ (Riemann mapping Thm.). We hypothesize that $f^2$ is your desired surjection and for some $y \in \mathbb{C}$, we look for $z_y \in \Omega_1$ such that $f(z_y)^2 = y$. First, there is some $w_y \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $w_y^2 = y$ (Fundamental theorem of algebra). W.l.o.g., $\mathrm{Im}(w_y) >-1$, else choose $-w_y$ instead of $w_y$. Then, by bijectivity, find $z_y \in \Omega_1$ such that $f(z_y) = w_y$ and you are done.
